# React-to-print: how to change state in onAfterPrint when closing print window

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am using react-to-print library, and using that, I want to change a state when closing print window.

When I click cancel button, it works fine. However, if I click X (exit) button, it will crash.

I have the following code.

```
<ReactToPrint
  trigger={() => (
    ...
  )}
  content={() => ...}
  onBeforePrint={() => { this.setState({ printState: true}) }}
  onAfterPrint={() => { this.setState({ printState: false }) }}  
  closeAfterPrint
/>
```

Here's the error message

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be it, but try using `onAfterPrint={() => this.handlePrintAfter()}`

Comment: sorry That didn't work. also, I updated my code above

Answer (score 0):

This is a very edge case where your component is re-rendered after the dialog opened, so you have to use `flushSync` as outlined in the React-DOM docs here to force a full re-render before the dialog opens:

https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/flushSync#usage

Hope that helps.